# Gatling ElFileBody and parameter + static test

Tags: gatling

I want to parameterize just the NIN (05129996961) in this example (I have it in session).

```
 "subject": {
            "reference": "urn:uuid:c1015cfa-d6b6-4f06-8150-ced7dbea759c",
            "type": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-Patient",
            "display": "Patient 05129996961"
          },
```

Is there a way to say i.e.  "display": "Patient + ${nin}" or something similar in the ElFileBody?

Comment: What's the question? Is there possibility for add Gatling EL inside the json? - Yes it's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain old Gatling EL:

```
 "subject": {
            "reference": "urn:uuid:c1015cfa-d6b6-4f06-8150-ced7dbea759c",
            "type": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-Patient",
            "display": "Patient #{nin}"
          },
```

Comment: another challenge is how to put in a value like this:

  .exec(session=>{
      val fullUrl = session("fullUrl").as[Vector[String]]
      println(s"fullUrl: ${fullUrl(0)}")
      session})

into the json request body above. As in using it as a string "s" before.